# Routing table size and lookup speed

Tags: networking, routes, router, tcp

I can't wrap my head around routing tables. Is it true that every router has a table with routes to **every** ip address in the world? Wouldn't that make the tables huge and thus make the lookup slow?

Comment: Individual addresses are not advertised on the public internet. Only network prefixes are advertised, and the ISPs will not advertise a prefix longer than `/24`, but host addresses are `/32` (longer than `/24`). Routers route packets toward networks, and the end-network takes care of getting the packet to the destination host. Also, networks are aggregated where possible to reduce the number of routing entries. For example, `198.18.128.0/24`, `198.18.129.0/24`, `198.18.130.0/24`, and `198.18.131.0/24` can be aggregated to a single `198.18.128.0/22` prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routers with few interfaces need only few entries - a home router with a single subnet inside and the Internet outside just requires two entries.

Routing is a distributed job, every router only needs to know the routes it's got connected somewhere. Hops more remote to the final destination might only match a very short prefix - the default route with /0, or maybe /8 or /12 specific routes. The closer a hop is to the destination, the more refined (=longer prefix) the route is likely to get, with a prefix of /24, /29 or even /32.

The more interfaces, subnets and thus *choices* a router has got, the longer the routing table gets. Internet core routers may have many 100,000 to more than a million routing entries (thx Ron). More powerful routers use special, content-addressable memory ([TCAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_memory#Ternary_CAMs)) to enable single-step lookup.

Comment: "_Internet core routers may have many 100,000 routing entries._" It is much closer to 1,000,000 entries today.